# Implementation of Queue using circular Linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, queue

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

void addcll(struct node **, struct node **, int);
void displaycll(struct node *);

void main() 
{
    struct node *front, *rear;

    front = rear = NULL;

    addcll(&front, &rear, 56);
    addcll(&front, &rear, 12);
    displaycll(front);
}

void addcll(struct node **f, struct node **r, int item) {
    struct node *q;
    q = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    q->data = item;
    if (*f == NULL) {
        *f = q;
    }
    else {
        (*r)->link = q;
        (*r) = q;
        (*r)->link = *f;
    }
}

void displaycll(struct node *f) {
    struct node *q, *p;
    q = f;
    p = NULL;
    while (q != p) {
        printf("%d \n", q->data);
        q = q->link;
        p = f;
    }
}
```

Unable to figure out exactly where is the error please help !
Also I am beginner to data structures . Please give me some suggestion of book or online resources where I can learn and practice these concepts

Comment: You're never setting the rear pointer when the first item is added. Neither are you setting the link in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addcll` is wrong. the rear pointer should *always* be reset on a queue back-push, and the link of the node pushed should *always* be set to the content of `front`, even in the case when the first node is added, btw.

```
void addcll(struct node **f, struct node **r, int item) 
{
    struct node *q = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    q->data = item;
    if (*f == NULL) {
        *f = q;
    }
    else {
        (*r)->link = q;
    }
    (*r) = q; // here
    (*r)->link = *f; // and here.
}
```